# .Net Regex to retrieve substring with start and end string exclusive

Tags: regex

I need to use Regex to retrieve substring from some text. The pattern of the targets is they all start and end with a particular string, for example I need to get everything between "abc" and "def" from below:

> xxxxxxxxxxx**abc**xxxxxxxxx**def**xxxxxxxx

The expression I'm using is

> abc.*def

Because ".*" means any characters of any length.

But for some cases in this task, I don't need "abc" and "def" to be retrieved, only everything in between. I can use string operation to trim the head and tail but I wonder if there is a Regex that does the job.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just make your regex abc(.*)def to only capture the middle part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lookaround will help in this case. Here's the expression:

```
(?<=abc).*(?=def)
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using a lookaround instead of doing something like this: `abc(.*)def`?

Comment: "abc(.*)def" will match the whole "abcXXXdef" string, then treat "XXX" as a capture group. With the lookaround expression "(?<=abc).*(?=def)", you ONLY match "XXX" from the get go and don't have to mess with captures. It's just a bit cleaner.